# SQL0007N invalid character with sqlalchemy in jupyter-notebook

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, db2, db2-luw

%%sql
Select Per_capita_Income, Community_Area_Name
from CENSUS_DATA
Where Per_Capita_Income < 11000;

- ibm_db_sa://ztl80401:***@125f9f61-9715-46f9-9399-c8177b21803b.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud:30426/BLUDB
  (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0007N  The statement was not processed because a character that is not supported in SQL statements was included in the SQL statement.  Invalid character: "\".  Text preceding the invalid character: "ame from CENSUS_DATA".  SQLSTATE=42601 SQLCODE=-7
  [SQL: Select Per_capita_Income, Community_Area_Name
  from CENSUS_DATA 
  Where Per_Capita_Income < 11000;]
  (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

Hello,

I can't get this query to pull the Country Area names where the Per capita Income is less than 11000. what is wrong with my query? I am using Jupyter Notebooks and my database is DB2. Please help. thanks!

Comment: It seems that somehow your SQL statement includes a backslash (\\) and the driver or engine doesn't like it. Check the exact SQL statement for any extra/invalid character in it.

Comment: please edit your question to add in plain text the output of `pip freeze` on your system, and also specify your python version, and your operating-system details.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you for your response. This is my new query>> %%sql 
select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, PER_CAPITA_INCOME
from CENSUS_DATA 
where PER_CAPITA_INCOME < 11000;
 But, I still got a new error code >> SQL0206N  "PER_CAPITA_INCOME" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703 SQLCODE=-206

Comment: @mao Thanks for your response. I am using Python 3.8.2,  macOS. I haven't tried pip freeze and the output. I'll try that later today...

Comment: @mao I am using Jupyter notebooks,

Comment: Could it be that the data type for PER_CAPITA_INCOME is string instead of Integer? %%sql 
select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, PER_CAPITA_INCOME
from CENSUS_DATA 
where PER_CAPITA_INCOME < '11000';
​
 * ibm_db_sa://ztl80401:***@125f9f61-9715-46f9-9399-c8177b21803b.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud:30426/BLUDB
(ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0206N  "PER_CAPITA_INCOME" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703 SQLCODE=-206

Comment: Please stop pasting code in the comments. Update your question with and changes\progress you have made.